# Proof of Choi-Effros Theorem for Operator Systems in Paulsen's Book

Tags: proof-explanation, operator-algebras

I am trying to understand the proof of Theorem 13.1 in Paulsen's Book ``Completely Bounded Maps and Operator Algebras''.

**Theorem** *If $S$ is a matrix-ordered $*$-vector space with an Archimedean matrix order unit $e$, then there exists a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, an operator system $S_1\subseteq\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$, and a complete order isomorphism $\varphi\colon S\rightarrow S_1$ with $\varphi(e)=I_\mathcal{H}$.*

The proof starts as follows: Let $$P_n=\{\varphi\colon S\rightarrow M_n\,|\,\varphi\text{ completely positive,} \varphi(e)=I_n\}$$
where $I_n$ is the identity matrix. Define
$$
J:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{\varphi\in P_n}\oplus\,\varphi\colon S\rightarrow\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{\varphi\in P_n}\oplus\, M_n^\varphi
$$
where the latter direct sum is in the $l^\infty$ sense. Clearly, by the choice of $\varphi$'s, $(x_{ij})\in\mathcal{C}_n$ implies $(J(x_{ij}))\geq 0$ where $\mathcal{C}_n$ denotes a cone from the matrix ordering. And the proof goes on...

(1) First of all I am a bit confused by the notation. Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{\varphi\in P_n}\oplus M_n^\varphi$ simply a notation for the direct sum
, i.e. could we also write
$$
\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty\bigoplus_{\varphi\in P_n} M_n^\varphi
$$
for this space?

(2) Secondly, how do we know that $J$ is well defined, i.e. why is $\Vert J(s)\Vert_\infty$ for $s\in S$ bounded?

(3) And finally, why is it clear that $(J(x_{ij}))\geq 0$ holds? Since multiplication in $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{\varphi\in P_n}\oplus M_n^\varphi$ is defined component wise, is it, because we know $\varphi$ is completely positive, each component of $(J(x_{ij}))$ can be decomposed into an Hermitian square, i.e. $aa^*$ for some $a$ and thus $(J(x_{ij}))$ can be decomposed into the component wise product of the the tuples consisting of those roots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. When $s$ is selfadjoint the order unit property gives you $c>0$ such that $-c\,e≤s≤c\,e$ and so $-c\,I_n≤\varphi(s)≤c\,I_n$, so $\|\varphi(s)\|≤c$. For arbitrary $s$ you have $s=s_1+i s_2$ with $s_1,s_2$ selfadjoint, and so
   $$
   \|\varphi(s)\|≤\|\varphi(s_1)\|+\|\varphi(s_2)\|≤c_1+c_2.
   $$
3. Yes, positivity in an $\ell^\infty$-direct sum is defined component-wise. If $s≥0$ then all components will be of the form $\varphi(s)$ with $\varphi$ ucp and hence positive. For the complete positivity you need to notice that
   $$
   M_k\big(\bigoplus_j M_{n(j)}(\mathbb C)\big)\simeq \bigoplus_j M_k(M_{n(j)}(\mathbb C)\big).
   $$

Comment: I already accepted this answer, but I just realized, that 2. is still a bit unclear to me. Why is it enough to show $\Vert\varphi(a)\Vert\leq c$ for positive $a$, i.e. for $a\in C_1$? (I assume there is a typo and $a=s$?) And aren't you just using the order unit property? Where do you need that it is also Archimedean?

Comment: Because you are using the supremum norm on the right, so you need to show that all components are uniformly bounded. And yes, it was a typo, and yes it was the order unit property. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I understand that we have to show that the components are uniformly bounded, but why is it enough to show it for a positive element $s$?

Comment: You are totally right, it is not enough. I have edited the answer, please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Yes, you  are right here. The point is that the direct sum runs over all 'unital' completely positive maps $S\to M_n$, where $n$ can vary. I admit that the notation is a bit awkward. The following would perhaps be a bit cleaner:

Let $P= \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty P_n$ and then consider the space $\bigoplus_{\varphi \in P} M_{n(\varphi)}$.

I will stick with this proposed notation.

(2) Your map is $J(x) = (\varphi(x))_{\varphi \in P}, x\in S$. Note then that $\|\varphi\|= 1$ for all $\varphi \in S$ (this is a good exercise) Hence,
$\|J(x)\|= \sup_{\varphi\in P}\|\varphi(x)\| \le \|x\|$ for $x\in S$ and thus $J$ is a contraction.

(3) The way I see this, the following happens:

We want to show that the inflated map
$$M_n(J): M_n(S)\to M_n\left(\bigoplus_{\varphi\in P} M_{n(\varphi)}\right)$$
is positive. However, note that
$$M_n\left(\bigoplus_{\varphi\in P} M_{n(\varphi)}\right) \cong \bigoplus_{\varphi \in P} M_n(M_{n(\varphi)})$$
so it suffices to show that the composition
$$M_n(S)\to \bigoplus_{\varphi \in P} M_n(M_{n(\varphi)})$$
is positive. This composition is precisely the map
$$z \mapsto (M_n(\varphi)(z))_{\varphi \in P}$$
which is positive because each $M_n(\varphi)$ is positive.

Comment: Note that $\|\varphi\|$ makes no sense:  $S$ is an abstract operator system, so it has no norm.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Each $M_n(S)$ does have a norm, coming from the positivity cones. This is proven very explicitly in Paulsen's book.

Comment: Yes, of course. But it is not information that is initially given with the abstract operator system. It can be deduced from it, the same way that it can be deduced that the abstract operator system is isomorphic to a concrete one (which is what is being proved here).  So, I don't think you can take it for granted in this context.

Comment: @MartinArgerami At this point in Paulsen's book, this is already established, so I don't see any harm in using it.

Comment: Fair enough. $ $